# Disabling the debugging mode in socket-io client on react native

Tags: react-native, webpack, websocket, socket.io

I am using socket-io in order to connect to the server in my react native app. the problem is that the socket debug logs are filling the console. Is there a way to disable the debugging mode in react native. in their document, https://socket.io/docs/v4/logging-and-debugging/#removing-debug-from-your-browser-bundle, they show how to remove it using Webpack. is their a way to do that in react native